# How do I easily convert from one collection type to another during a filter, map, flatMap in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary, filter, implicit-conversion

Suppose I have a `List[Int]`, and I want to call `toString` on each element, and get back the result as a `Vector[String]`.

What are the various ways to do this in Scala? Is there a solution with a minimal amount of explicit typing? — i.e., I want to specify that I want a `Vector` rather than a `List`, but I'd like the `String` argument to be inferred from the filter function.

Or should I explicitly pass a `CanBuildFrom` instance? Where do I get these from — for `Seq`s, `Set`s and `Map`s?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### Using breakOut

Use `breakOut` as the `CanBuildFrom` and let the typer know what you want your result type to be (unfortunately you need to specify String here)

```
scala> import collection.breakOut
import collection.breakOut

scala> List(1, 2, 3)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> res0.map(_.toString)(breakOut) : Vector[String]
res2: Vector[String] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

---

### Using to[Collection] (starting with Scala 2.10.0)

Scala 2.10.0 introduced an easy way to convert a collection to another collection:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).map(_.toString).to[Vector]
res0: Vector[String] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

---

### Using toIndexedSeq

Alternatively ask for an `IndexedSeq` explicitly:

```
scala> res0.map(_.toString).toIndexedSeq
res4: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

If you want to do this without creating the intermediate `List`, then:

```
scala> res0.view.map(_.toString).toIndexedSeq
res5: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

---

### Using Natural Transformations

You could do it (awkwardly, but more generally) using *natural transformations*

```
scala> trait Trans[F[_], G[_]] {
 | def f2g[A](f : F[A]) : G[A]
 | }
defined trait Trans
```

Now provide a typeclass instance from the List ~> Vector transformation:

```
scala> implicit val List2Vector = new Trans[List, collection.immutable.Vector] {
 | def f2g[A](l : List[A]) : Vector[A] = l.map(identity[A])(collection.breakOut)
 | }
List2Vector: java.lang.Object with Trans[List,scala.collection.immutable.Vector] = $anon$1@56329755
```

Define a wrapper and an implicit conversion:

```
scala> class Clever[M[_], A](ma : M[A]) { def to[N[_]](implicit t : Trans[M, N]) : N[A] = t.f2g(ma) }
defined class Clever

scala> implicit def ma2clever[M[_], A](ma : M[A]) = new Clever[M, A](ma)
ma2clever: [M[_],A](ma: M[A])Clever[M,A]
```

Then:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).map(_.toString).to[Vector]
res4: Vector[java.lang.String] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks, using `breakOut` seems to work well for `map` and `flatMap`, but not with `filter`, which does not accept a `CanBuildFrom`. I can use the `toIndexedSeq` for `Vector`s, but what if I want an arbitrary collection, for which a `CanBuildFrom` is available? Do I have to go through natural transformations?

Comment: @JPP - depends on your use-case, I suspect. Personally I wouldn't use natural transformations - seems like a lot of pain for not much gain. Also, why would the *standard* form of a collection-type (e.g. `Vector` for `IndexedSeq`) not be good enough?

Comment: I agree, the standard form is usually good enough, and together with views, we avoid the creation of an intermediary representation. I was just curious as to if there was a way to do it. I'll leave the question open for a while and then accept your answer if nothing else presents itself.

Comment: @JPP `filter` cannot return a different collection.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral or oxbow_lakes, Is there a better way to do this in 2.10? Would it be worth updating the answer?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet There's something, indeed. I added a new section, right below the breakOut, which is the most efficient one in terms of performance.

Comment: Just as a precaution... if the original collection is a `Set`, you will probably want to call `to` before `map`. Otherwise, the intermediate collection will fillter out duplicates. Consider: `Set("Bob", "Don", "Susan").map(_.length).to[Vector]` yields `Vector(3, 5)` instead of `Vector(3, 3, 5)`. You probably want `Set("Bob", "Don", "Susan").to[Vector].map(_.length)` instead.