# Scala: Yielding from one type of collection to another

Tags: scala, collections, yield

Concerning the *yield* command in Scala and the following example:

```
val values = Set(1, 2, 3)
val results = for {v <- values} yield (v * 2)
```

Can anyone explain how Scala knows which type of collection to yield into? I know it is based on *values*, but how would I go about writing code that replicates *yield*?

Is there any way for me to change the type of the collection to yield into? In the example I want *results* to be of type *List* instead of *Set*.

Failing this, what is the best way to convert from one collection to another? I know about _:*, but as a *Set* is not a *Seq* this does not work. The best I could find thus far is *val listResults = List() ++ results*.

Ps. I know the example does not following the recommended functional way (which would be to use *map*), but it is just an example.

Comment: A minor note, while I find map more convenient, I would not call it more or less functional than for, as it is exactly the same thing. for{v <- values} yield (v*2) is compiled as values.map{v => v * 2} (sort of macro expansion). It is definitely not a loop : the implementation of map in Set is responsible for looping if needed, not the for comprehension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I easily convert from one collection type to another during a filter, map, flatMap in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593131/how-do-i-easily-convert-from-one-collection-type-to-another-during-a-filter-map)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `for` comprehensions are translated by compiler to `map`/`flatMap`/`filter` calls using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/can-someone-explain-scalas-yield/1059501#1059501) scheme.

[This excellent answer by Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout/1716558#1716558) answers your first question.

To change the type of result collection, you can use `collection.breakout` (also explained in the post I linked above.)

```
scala> val xs = Set(1, 2, 3)
xs: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> val ys: List[Int] = (for(x <- xs) yield 2 * x)(collection.breakOut)
ys: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

You can convert a `Set` to a `List` using one of following ways:

```
scala> List.empty[Int] ++ xs
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> xs.toList
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

---

**Recommended read:** [The Architecture of Scala Collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html)

Comment: nice! so you _can_ use `breakOut` with for comprehensions

Comment: How on earth did I miss the toList method?! Thanks a lot, the links are very informative.

Comment: Personally, I prefer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1052476/53013) to the one you chose to explain how for comprehensions are translated. Then again, you answers the one you linked, and I answered this other, so maybe we are biased. :-)

Comment: @Daniel: I never came across that thread before (dates to time when I hadn't even heard of Scala). That is an excellent answer. I upvoted it, and also linked it in my answer. :-)

Comment: You shouldn't have removed the link to your own answer. It's a good answer too, and, sometimes, people learn something by comparing different answers to the same question.

Comment: `breakOut` <- hugely powerful tool.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `map`/`flatmap`/`filter` instead of for comprehensions, you can use `scala.collection.breakOut` to create a different type of collection:

```
scala> val result:List[Int] = values.map(2*)(scala.collection.breakOut)
result: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

If you wanted to build your own collection classes (which is the closest thing to "replicating yield" that makes any sense to me), you should have a look at [this tutorial](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/04/creating-custom-traversable.html).

Comment: You can actually do that with for too (to my surprise): (for(v <- values) yield v*2)(breakOut)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val values = Set(1, 2, 3)
val results = for {v <- values} yield (v * 2).toList
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.